# Clipping images from a HTML5 canvas (Konva)

Tags: canvas, konvajs

I want to create a drag an drop game in Konva. Very similar to what they have here https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Animals_on_the_Beach_Game.html.

However I would like to have a interface for creating the game, where an author draws on a background image. Then it automatically generates the game based on those paths.

I have this piece of code for clipping my background image.

```
        return _.map(this.props.areas, (area) => {
        return (
            <Group
                draggable={true}
                clipFunc={(ctx) => {
                    canvasDrawFuncMap[area.shape](ctx, area.coords);
                }}
            >
                <Image image={image} />
            </Group>
        );
    });
```

Are there any performance worries here. Considering that its redrawing the whole image each time. Then clipping it. Is there a better way to achieve this kind of clipping .

Also right now I am manually creating my clipFunctions and defining them in a map. Is there anyway for me to use Konva to generate these functions based on Konva shapes

Answer (score 0):

If you are worrying about the performance take a look into performance tips: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html

The cache may help a lot here.

Currently there are no documented ways to use Konva nodes as clip objects.